# Scroll UITableView Header?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, header

I have a custom UITableView header which I want to be able to scroll above the top of the table. Normally the header would stick to the top of the table, is it not possible to somehow change to scrolling ability so that it can go beyond that and scrolls with the cells in the table?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You want the header to be static and always displayed when the user scrolls the table? Or do you want the header to scroll with the table and thus disappear when the user scrolls down?

Comment: I want the header to scroll with the table, so if the user scrolls down, it disappears off the top of the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if that is the desired behavior you want, just put the `header` as the first cell's content. It is possible to customize any particular cell you want. `UITableViewDelegate` documentaion will help you in that matter.

PS: the whole point of using `tableView` header is to make it stick to the top of the window.

*EDIT:* If it is necessary that you have to do the way you want, then you can try this: move your `tableView` a little down by setting its `contentOffset`. eg: `myTableView.contentOffset= CGPointMake(0,heightOfYourView)` . Now add `yourView` at the top

Comment: I understand that. I did this, however because my table gets core data records it has caused a whole heap of problems which I have since struggled to avoid. So I was looking for an alternative solution of having this custom view with the table but not actually as port of the cell index.

Comment: Well i have edited my answer. Try it now. Also, you should have mentioned this in your question.

Comment: your header should be in a separate tableview section from the core data rows. this will ensure the first core data row is still index 0

Comment: Aqs, I have tried this but it makes zero difference. Sorry I didn't mention my situation in the questions previously as well.

Answer (score 4):

```
myTableView.tableViewHeader = myCustomTableHeaderView;
```

This would set `myCustomTableHeaderView` as the header of your table view and it would scroll with the table view.

Answer (score 1):

By implementing `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` for section of index `0`, you can instead have the header as the first section that should disappear when it scrolls. In this way, it's not a header for the whole UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one header for the whole table, can't you just set the `tableHeaderView` property?

Comment: I have one section with one header for the whole table. I have added my view to the header, but normally the header sticks to the top of the table, I want it to scroll with the cells. Or am I not understanding?

Answer (score 0):

You might, like me, have been searching for the tableHeaderView property. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446979/uitableview-directly-setting-tableheaderview-property-vs-implementing-viewfo) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Grouped TableView Style and in your ViewDidLoad method, add following line of code:

```
myTableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
myTableView.opaque=NO;
myTableView.backgroundView=nil;
```

Also in nib file, you should clear background color of grouped table;

Answer (score -2):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat sectionHeaderHeight = 40;//Change as per your table header hight
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y<=sectionHeaderHeight&&scrollView.contentOffset.y>=0) {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0, 0, 0);
    } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y>=sectionHeaderHeight) {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-sectionHeaderHeight, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```