# Identifying a segmented control view in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I'd want to build a view similar to this, with grouped table and a segmented control, from the Settings app:

[image: Settings app - WiFi]

Should it be an unique `UITableView` with a segmented control in a `UITableViewCell`? Or is it a segmented control, and then a `UITableView`? I tried placing a segmented control as a subview of an `UITableViewCell` in Interface Builder, with same size and setting the cell's background color to clear. But when I run the app, the segmented control's width is higher than the cell's, and even goes out of the screen...

Thanks

Comment: I guess, it would be in UITableViewCell with a section title for that row.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess it is placed on a section footer. But in the end it is just guessing, as we dont have the code to see how the view hierarchy is set up.

---

The segmented control could be in the last sections footer. If "manual" gets activated, the table gets reloaded but now with one more section. This section holds the cells that now appears.

---

an example for tableview vs section header (footers are to be treated like headers): https://stackoverflow.com/a/6447095/106435.

Comment: You're right, we don't have such code, I just wanted to know if someone did something like this and how. The screenshot is from a Wi-Fi network details view in Settings, and it has the visual structure cells-segmented control-cells, so I'm not sure if this could be a header/footer...

Comment: the segmented control could be in the last sections footer. if "manual" gets activated, the table gets reloaded bit now with one more section. this section holds the cells that now appears.